# Importing csv file into MongoDB with wiredtiger and zlib compression

Tags: mongodb, compression, zlib

I am using MongoDB 2.8.0 RC and I installed WiredTiger with 3 compressors:

```
./configure --enable-bzip2 --enable-snappy --enable-zlib
```

And now my question is: How do i run mongod so when I import csv file it will compress it with zlib? Then I need to clear database and import the file with 2 other compressors and compare sizes of collections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, at least for now, bzip2 is not one of the supported block compressors for MongoDB 2.8 (snappy and zlib are the only two supported).  Secondly, if you have the 2.8.0 release candidate, then you don't need to build WiredTiger yourself, it is included with MongoDB.  I wrote up 2 blog posts on how I compared the block compression of WiredTiger:

- [Post 1 - Initial testing, including methodology](http://comerford.cc/wordpress/2014/11/12/mongodb-2-8-new-wiredtiger-storage-engine-adds-compression/)
- [Post 2 - Follow up testing with patch for bug discovered in post 1](http://comerford.cc/wordpress/2014/11/17/mongodb-2-8-improving-wiredtiger-performance/)

They include the settings I used to enable/disable the compression in YAML format (be careful, the case for enabling WiredTiger changed in rc1, it is now "wiredTiger" rather than all lower case):

- [snappy config example](https://gist.github.com/comerford/0bc6b9e420f54db2b185)
- [zlib config example](https://gist.github.com/comerford/d75af49fe3d4a6b53d0a)
- [no compression WT config example](https://gist.github.com/comerford/5b7e0474e75667782b88)
- [mmap config example](https://gist.github.com/comerford/05c445d64fd0ea1bad23)

I would recommend this approach, that is separate data paths for the databases you intend to evaluate for comparison.  Unless you have a *very* compelling reason to do so, I would limit testing to just the supported compressors for now, otherwise you will likely be spending your time trying to integrate a non-standard WT engine that you have compiled separately into MongoDB (which might be interesting, but is it the real end goal here?) rather than testing the compression itself.

Comment: Could you explain me how am I suppose to use those YAML Config. I am really new at this and need step by step instruction. Thank you for your time.

Comment: The simplest way is `mongod -f /path/to/config` - I don't think I will write a step by step guide because it's not really appropriate - testing block compression methods and alternative storage engines in pre-release versions is generally a pretty advanced topic and you should be familiar with basic MongoDB operations (such as how to use a config file) before attempting it. Once the software is released there will be production level documentation including tutorials

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what i have been looking for.